# JavaScript custom event trigger issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a details view which contains 2 buttons for Create/Edit.

On click of these buttons, I display a modal popup

```
var modal = new MyAppModalView({
    model: person
});

modal.bind("afterSave", function(values) {
    self.showMessage('Sucessfully submitted for saving', false, true);
    return true;
});
```

Also within the Modal view code, I have:

```
if (isNew) {
//Create flow
    this.model.save(myJSON, {
        url: "myapp/persons/create",
        success: function() {
            self.trigger("afterSave");
            self.removeModal();
        }
    });
} else {
//Edit flow
    this.model.save(myJSON, {
        url: "myapp/persons/edit",
        success: function() {
            self.trigger("afterSave");
            self.removeModal();
        }
    });
}
```

Now after save for both Create/Edit, I trigger an event for afterSave

While the event is triggered for the Create flow, it does not get triggered for the Edit flow. I am not sure why does that happen?

I tried binding 2 separate evens for the modal (afterSave/afterUpdate) and triggering each for Create/Edit; still the trigger does not get called for Edit (afterUpdate)

---

The code is called within saveAction as below;

```
var MyAppModalView = BaseModal.extend({
....
saveAction: function(event) {
            var self = this;

}
});
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: No error...Only the event does not get triggered...so the code ...self.showMessage('Sucessfully submitted for sav...does not get called for Edit flow

Comment: Have you tried move `afterSave` bind event into the function and then just call it for the bind and for the trigger?

Comment: Are you sure that it's reaching your handler's code?

Comment: The intention behind the `self` variable is obvious. However, you do not show how it is assigned. Have you checked if `self` always points to the right object ? Please post more code, showing how and where you assign its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to have a different URL to POST (create) and PUT (save) too.  That would trim your code down to :

```
this.model.save(myJSON, {
    success: function() {
        self.trigger("afterSave");
        self.removeModal();
    }
});
```

If removeModal() is being called then "afterSave" is being triggered but your edit view is causing the afterSave message to not be shown somehow. You could replace your success message with an alert to verify that is the case.

Comment: Thx...I just tried that...But it does not set the url correctly in this case...it tries to literally make a call to url as "function(){..."

Comment: My apologies its Collection that allows you to override URL.  Irregardless you should be able to use the same URL to POST (create) and PUT (update) to.  Also please consider updating your question to state if removeModal is being called.